# HTTP 406 Response when getting Token with Postman

Tags: acumatica

I'm getting an HTTP 406 response from Acumatica's API when trying to get an access token using the OAuth Resource Owner Password flow.  I'm using Postman 10.17.  This same request was working last week.  It seems to only be happening with Acumatica Saas installations.  On-prem installations seem to be OK.  I've tried 22 R2 and 23 R1 sites.  Has anybody ran across this?

Headers:
[image: Headers]

Body:
[image: Body]

Comment: Do you use UserName@TenantName in the username field or just UserName?

Comment: Just UserName.  No tenant.

Comment: Try to use UserName@TenantName or UserName@TenantLoginName.

Comment: I get the same 406 response when adding the @Tenant

Comment: Finally I found a request that worked in a multi-tenant environment.
client_id=8B9EE61E-E49D-73C6-EFF2-52BAE3141252@TenantName
I am not sure TenantName is Login Name or Tenant Name.

Comment: One more thing: Do you use Desktop Agent or Cloud Agent? Our consultants are experiencing the same problem, they are getting 406 when using the Cloud Agent.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by agent?  I'm using desktop app for Postman but, the issue seems to only happen on Saas (cloud) installations of Acumatica.  There's no issue with a local sandbox installation or an on-prem Acumatica site.  I just caught another update for postman so, I'll see what that does.

Comment: It looks like something is wrong with the current version of Postman Desktop. Our Acumatica consultants were facing the very same issue than you have. The solution was to use the web based postman with desktop agent. If you need help in that, lets continue this discussion in the chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue. I removed the Postman User-Agent header and it worked again. I can only speculate why this was done by Acumatica, so I don't :)

[How to remove User Agent header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfHnT.png)